# Checking method execution order in Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check the correct execution order of methods in a Python (3.9) class (see example below).

Here some example class, that executes the methods in the desired order:

```
class Example:
    def setup(self):
        print("setup")
        return True
        
    def pre_loop(self):
        print("pre_loop")
        return True
        
    def loop_func1(self):
        print("loop_func1")
        return True
        
    def loop_func2(self):
        print("loop_func2")
        return True
        
    def loop_func3(self):
        print("loop_func3")
        return True
        
    def post_loop(self):
        print("post_loop")
        return True
        
    def shutdown(self):
        print("shutdown")
        return True
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Example()
    
    obj.setup()
    obj.pre_loop()
    
    for i in range(3):
        print(f"Index {i}")
        obj.loop_func1()
        obj.loop_func2()
        obj.loop_func3()
        
    obj.post_loop()
    obj.shutdown()
```

In the final application the class methods are called by another app and therefore the correct execution order can be violated.

I tried to use a decorator that monitors the execution order and raises an exception, if it is violated.
Like shown here (not working):

```
from functools import wraps

class Example:
    previous_func = None
    
    def monitor_exec_order(allowed):
        def decorator(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.previous_func in allowed:
                    raise Exception("Execution order violated.")
                result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                if result:
                    self.previous_func = func
                return result
            return wrapper
        return decorator
    
    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(None,))
    def setup(self):
        print("setup")
        return True
    
    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(setup,))
    def pre_loop(self):
        print("pre_loop")
        return True
        
    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(pre_loop, loop_func3))
    def loop_func1(self):
        print("loop_func1")
        return True
        
    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(loop_func1,))
    def loop_func2(self):
        print("loop_func2")
        return True
        
    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(loop_func2,))
    def loop_func3(self):
        print("loop_func3")
        return True
        
    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(loop_func3,))
    def post_loop(self):
        print("post_loop")
        return True
        
    def shutdown(self):
        print("shutdown")
        return True
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Example()
    
    obj.setup()
    try:
        obj.pre_loop()
        
        for i in range(3):
            print(f"Index {i}")
            obj.loop_func1()
            obj.loop_func2()
            obj.loop_func3()
            
        obj.post_loop()
    finally:
        obj.shutdown()
```

But the comparision in the wrapper method isn't working as desired. If I print it a see why but I don't know how to fix it.

```
> print(self.previous_func)
<function Example.setup at 0x03517970>
> print(allowed)
(<function Example.setup at 0x03517AD8>,)
```

Can you please give me any hints to fix the problem.

Comment: In your wrapper you are missing the `self`: `result = func(*args, **kwargs)`. But how does this even run for you? `loop_func1` references `loop_func3` which is not yet defined.

Comment: Yeah, the `self` was missing, forgot to copy. And the `loop_func1` references is also a problem, tried it up to now without the loop...bad idea. But a idea came to my mind that I could simply check for the function name. Seems like I just needed a different perspective for a moment...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that in my case, it is sufficient, to check the functions name.

Here is the working example code:

```
from functools import wraps


class Example:
    previous_func = None

    def monitor_exec_order(allowed):
        def decorator(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
                ok = False
                if self.previous_func is None and None in allowed:
                    ok = True
                elif self.previous_func.__name__ in allowed:
                    ok = True

                if ok:
                    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    raise Exception("Execution order violated.")

                if result:
                    self.previous_func = func
                return result

            return wrapper

        return decorator

    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=(None,))
    def setup(self):
        print("setup")
        return True

    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=("setup",))
    def pre_loop(self):
        print("pre_loop")
        return True

    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=("pre_loop", "loop_func3"))
    def loop_func1(self):
        print("loop_func1")
        return True

    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=("loop_func1",))
    def loop_func2(self):
        print("loop_func2")
        return True

    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=("loop_func2",))
    def loop_func3(self):
        print("loop_func3")
        return True

    @monitor_exec_order(allowed=("loop_func3",))
    def post_loop(self):
        print("post_loop")
        return True

    def shutdown(self):
        print("shutdown")
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Example()
    obj.setup()

    try:
        obj.pre_loop()

        for i in range(2):
            obj.loop_func1()
            obj.loop_func2()
            obj.loop_func3()

        obj.post_loop()
    finally:
        obj.shutdown()
```